# Flink Capacity Planning For Large State in YARN Cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have hit a roadblock moving an app at Production scale and was hoping to get some guidance. Application is pretty common use case in stream processing but does require maintaining large number of keyed states. We are processing 2 streams - one of which is a daily burst of stream (normally around 50 mil but could go upto 100 mil in one hour burst) and other is constant stream of around 70-80 mil per hour. We are doing a low level join using CoProcess function between the two keyed streams. CoProcess function needs to refresh (upsert) state from the daily burst stream and decorate constantly streaming data with values from state built using bursty stream. All of the logic is working pretty well in a standalone Dev environment. We are throwing about 500k events of bursty traffic for state and about 2-3 mil of data stream. We have 1 TM with 16GB memory, 1 JM with 8 GB memory and 16 slots (1 per core on the server) on the server. We have been taking savepoints in case we need to restart app for with code changes etc. App does seem to recover from state very well as well. Based on the savepoints, total volume of state in production flow should be around 25-30GB.

At this point, however, we are trying deploy the app at production scale. App also has a flag that can be set at startup time to ignore data stream so we can simply initialize state. So basically we are trying to see if we can initialize the state first and take a savepoint as test. At this point we are using 10 TM with 4 slots and 8GB memory each (idea was to allocate around 3 times estimated state size to start with) but TMs keep getting killed by YARN with a GC Overhead Limit Exceeded error. We have gone through quite a few blogs/docs on Flink Management Memory, off-heap vs heap memory, Disk Spill over, State Backend etc. We did try to tweak managed-memory configs in multiple ways (off/on heap, fraction, network buffers etc) but can’t seem to figure out good way to fine tune the app to avoid issues. Ideally, we would hold state in memory (we do have enough capacity in Production environment for it) for performance reasons and spill over to disk (which I believe Flink should provide out of the box?). It feels like 3x anticipated state volume in cluster memory should have been enough to just initialize state. So instead of just continuing to increase memory (which may or may not help as error is regarding GC overhead) we wanted to get some input from experts on best practices and approach to plan this application better.

Appreciate your input in advance!

Comment: Which statebackend are you using?
Are you using any special libraries in your application?

Comment: Robert, thanks for checking in. I am using HDFS statebackend and no other special libraries other than Kafka connectors of course.

Comment: Can you try the RocksDBStatebackend. That one stores the state on disk, thus putting less pressure on the GC

Comment: That was going to be one thing I would try next. In parallel, as we are moving from Spark to Flink, I also wanted to understand some of the nuances to fine tune the app configs to avoid GC Overhead Limit. Per everything I have read, Flink should be able to handle that much state and we are ok to up the memory as well. We just aren't sure how to capacity plan this yet for those figures. eg: are resources on TM/JM ok? Is checkpointing really needed to utilize disk spill over feature? If so, how often should we checkpoint? Is enabling off-heap recommended (i think so but not sure) etc.

Comment: FYI, I switched my app to RocksDB Backend and it does seem to behave much better. I am seeing a lot more bootstrap time from savepoints but I suppose that is expected. I'd still be interested in some capacity planning best practices. Getting GC overhead does scare us :). Thanks!

Comment: Robert Metzger's talk at Flink Forward 2017 in Berlin is a good resource: https://berlin.flink-forward.org/kb_sessions/keep-it-going-how-to-reliably-and-efficiently-operate-apache-flink/ Yes, using the RocksDB state backend is the only way to have state that can spill to disk. Checkpoints should be frequent enough that recovery times are tolerable (since recovery relies on rollback and stream replay).